# How can I find out how many people have taken my JavaScript quiz?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, metrics

On my website we have a test written in JavaScript and my task is to find how many people have taken the test? Is there a tool or Analytic program I can use to find this information? Is there somewhere in Google Analytics I can find how many times my JavaScript quiz was taken?

Comment: "Is there somewhere in Google Analytics I can find how many times my JavaScript quiz was taken" Well did you log it?

Comment: Where are you storing the test results? Wouldn't that tell you how many people took your test? Or is it just a random thing people interact with and you don't do anything with the results?

Answer (score 0):

GA will not automagically tell you this without modifying your quiz.

Assuming you've used the default GA implementation using gtag.js, you need to run the following piece of code once people have completed your quiz:

```
gtag('event', 'quiz-complete');
```

this will show up as in GA under Behavior and Events as "default" category, and "quiz-complete" action, with label as "(not set)".

If you want to get more advanced you could do the following to set the category and label yourself:

```
gtag('event', 'quiz-complete', {
  'event_category' : 'myquiz',
  'event_label' : 'myfirstquiz'
});
```